# How do I export backlog from versionone to JIRA?

Tags: jira, versionone

How do I export backlog from versionone to JIRA?

do I have an excel file, or xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the VersionOne API (or SDK) to extract the the VersionOne backlog items. The API allows the querying of data, returning either XML or JSON. I am not familiar with any Jira "1-step" import via the Jira UI but I know that you can use Jira's API to take the VersionOne output and map the values to corresponding Jira values.

The simplest way to get started is

1) Find out if there is a Jira import via the UI. If not, figure how to post items to Jira using Jira rest interface.

2) Get acquainted with performing VersionOne API queries. Here is a link to VersionOne API  http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library?v=api

Here is an example that you can put in your browser to get a listing of your stories from your backlog.

http://www.YourVersionOneInstance/rest-1.v1/Data/Story

You will see an xml output in your browser of a subset of the attributes that are contained in a story.

At this point, you will know how to extract data from VersionOne and post data to Jira.

Alternatively, if you really want to get into something really dirty, VersionOne has a Jira integration that you can decompose and/or modify to suit your needs.  This might give you a flavor of what it looks like to take a Jira defect and propogate to VersionOne.  This is the reverse of what you seek but if you like fiddling with WCF and SOAP, have at it.  I still recommend learning Jira Rest rather than the Jira Soap stuff.  Here is the source http://bit.ly/16r0wYR